# Mysql Getting balance from a table using triggers or mysql function

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `wallet` (
  `id` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `pg_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intrument_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `wallet` (`id`, `amount`, `type`, `pg_id`, `comments`, `intrument_type`, `user_id`, `date`) VALUES
(17, 50, 'CREDIT', 'xxxxq123', NULL, 'REFUND', 1, '2020-04-18'),
(18, 50, 'CREDIT', 'xxxxq123', NULL, 'REFUND', 1, '2020-04-18'),
(22, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(23, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(24, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(25, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(26, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(27, 110, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(28, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(29, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(30, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(31, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(32, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(33, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19'),
(34, 100, 'DEBIT', 'NONE', '0', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 1, '2020-04-19');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/196aff

I want to get the balance from this table.

If I use a single query to get the balance every time user wants to get a balance this query will run through all the transactions and that will make a heavy load to the user.

Instead of that, I want to write a function or trigger that will return the balance against the user id how can I do that?

Comment: Please add all relevant data to the question itself. The question should be complete even if the external resource is offline. Also please add what you have tried yourself. Also note that MySQL is usually capable to do this calculation on-the-fly, you would only *need* this if customers will have a large number of rows, so first check if it's actually expected to become too slow. It can lead to all [sorts of additional complications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48047933). To get you started: [general setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7570874), [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34091833)

Comment: update your question add  your code  ..  and add the expected  result based on you sample

Comment: You could do with an index on user_id and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you sqlfiddle  you could try using a conditional aggreagtion on type

```
select sum(case when `type`=  'CREDIT' THEN amount else -amount end) balance
from wallet
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/196aff/4